# Duplicate XML attribute in library project - any way to overcome?

Tags: android, xml

I have a custom view in a library project for quite some time and of course I've defined some XML attributes for it. To be specific, the XML attribute is "adSize".

I've just now added the Google Play Services" library project to my app and instantly there's an XML attribute naming conflict :

> Attribute "adSize" has already been defined

is there any way to overcome this problem that doesn't require me to update my library project (and all the apps that use my library). Is there some way to distinguish my attribute from Google's ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the lint settings to stop this fom throwing an error / lint error

The following is taken from [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)

> DuplicateIds
>   ------------ Summary: Checks for duplicate ids within a single layout
>
> Priority: 7 / 10 Severity: Warning Category: Correctness
>
> Within a layout, id's should be unique since otherwise findViewById()
>   can return an unexpected view.

You can just change the lint to be a warning if it is causing you issues with building your project.